# Sou iniciante e estou com dúvidas de como criar uma função que multiplique uma quantidade indeterminada de numeros no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante no mundo da programação e estou fazendo meus primeiros projetos em JavaScript. Esbarrei com esse problema simples que não estou conseguindo resolver. Preciso de uma função que faça uma operação em uma quantidade indeterminada de valores. Não precisa necessariamente ser uma multiplicação, gostaria de saber para qualquer operação (soma, subtração, multiplicação e divisão) como posso criar um função que calcule um numero indeterminado de valores que eu passar. Esbarro sempre na quantidade pré-determinada de valores. Por exemplo:

```
function mult (a,b) {
   console.log (a * b)
   
}

mult (2,3)
```

No caso acima só consigo passar dois valores. Se passar 3, ele descartará o terceiro elemento.

Gostaria de fazer uma quantidade indeterminada de valores, seja passando no `mult ()` 3 valores ou 10 valores a função multiplicasse todos. Como consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Isso é bem simples.

Toda função em JS tem uma variável local chamada `arguments`, que armazena os parâmetros da função ou argumentos em forma de Objeto

Nesse exemplo a função fará o que você quer

```
function mult (){ 
   let params = arguments;
   let result = 1;
   for(let i in params){
       result = result * params[i]; 
    }
   console.log(result);
   return result;
}
        
mult (2,3)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Não conhecia a variável arguments e foi extremamente útil esse novo conhecimento. Consegui utilizar esse método para multiplicação e para soma. Porém está dando errado para divisão e subtrações. Estou quebrando minha cabeça aqui.